# how to read/understand ruby/rails documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation

How can i read in documentation the methods that my object supports? For example, if i made a has_many association in rails, how to know which methods exists on that, what type is it? I know i can call each method but where is documented that? I could not find that in anywhere! I would like to see that in documentation, not always having to call methods method on the object... is there something like the javadoc where i see the methods that my object has and which he inherits?

Sorry about the stupid question but i'm new in ruby/rails =/

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/ has_many method

Comment: i saw that but for example where are the documentation of each method in the has_many collection? how i know i can call each method just with the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://api.rubyonrails.org/, type `has_many` at the field to the left. Then select firs result.

Comment: What about each method that i can call on that object? There is nothing there about that. (i'm using each method as an example but could be any other method that is not mentioned in documentation)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but maybe this will do http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_object.html#Object.inspect